# Multiple Pagination in view not working in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, pagination

This is my controller function:

```
function MarketingTaskmanagement(){
    /*..................................Mariya : Listing of Added Tasks , Pending Tasks and Finshed Tasks..................................*/
    $usrname = $this->Session->read('UserName');
    $emp_id = $this->Session->read('emp_id');

    $user_level = $emp_id;  //The User Level of the Loged User........

    /*...................................The Tasks selects here which are Assigned to this user............................................*/

    $this->set('user_level', $user_level);
    $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('status = 0', 'assigned_to = '.$user_level), 'limit' => 3, 'order' => array('TravancoMarketing.id' => 'DESC' ) );
    $data1 = $this->paginate('TravancoMarketing');
    $this->set('list_1', $data1);

    /*...................................................END..............................................................................*/

    /*................................The Tasks selects here which are Added by this user(Pending Tasks)..................................*/

    $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('status = 2', 'user_id = '.$user_level), 'limit' => 3, 'order' => array('TravancoMarketing.id' => 'DESC' ) );
    $data2 = $this->paginate('TravancoMarketing');
    $this->set('list_2', $data2);
    /*$this->set('list_2', '');*/

    /*...................................................END..............................................................................*/

    /*...................................The Tasks selects here which are Added by this user..............................................*/

    $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('status = 0', 'user_id = '.$user_level), 'limit' => 3, 'order' => array('TravancoMarketing.id' => 'DESC' ) );
    $data3 = $this->paginate('TravancoMarketing');
    $this->set('list_3', $data3);/*$this->set('list_3', '');*/

    /*...................................................END..............................................................................*/

    /*...................................The Tasks selects here which are Added by this user..............................................*/

    $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('status = 1', 'user_id = '.$user_level), 'limit' => 3, 'order' => array('TravancoMarketing.id' => 'DESC' ) );
    $data4 = $this->paginate('TravancoMarketing');
    $this->set('list_4', $data4);/*$this->set('list_3', '');*/

    /*...................................................END..............................................................................*/

    $this->render('Marketing/taskmanagement');
  }
```

This is my view page:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min.js');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('popup.js');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->css('forms'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function go_add_tasks(){
        //alert(1);
        window.location = "http://localhost/works/cakephp/Travanco/TravancoMarketing/MarketingAddtask"
    }
</script>
<div class="marketingcls">
    <div class="slabdiv">
        <div class="market-head">
            <h2 align="center">Welcome To Task Management</h2>

        </div>

        <? echo $this->element("marketinghead"); ?>
        <div style="width:1125px; height:auto; border:0px solid #999999; float:left; margin:50px;">
        <?php
        //$user_level = 2;
        if($user_level != 1){
        ?>

            <table width="100%" style="border:1px solid;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col" align="left">Assigned Tasks...</th>
              </tr>
              <?php 
              /*...................................The Tasks selects here which are Assigned to this user............................................*/
                if($list_1){
                $i=0;
                foreach($list_1 as $row1){ 
                    $assigned_id = $row1['TravancoMarketing']['id'];
                ?>
              <tr>
                <td>
                <?php echo $row1['TravancoMarketing']['title'];?>
                <input type="hidden" name="assigned_task_id" id="assigned_task_id_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $row1['TravancoMarketing']['id'];?>" />
                <?php echo $this->Html->link('...View More', '/TravancoMarketing/MarketingAssignedtask/'.$assigned_id, array('class'=>'textlinkclass', 'target'=>'_self')); ?>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
              }
              }
              ?>
              <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $this->paginator->numbers(); ?>
                    </td>
              </tr>

            </table>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
<br />
<?php //print_r($list);?>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <th width="34%">Set Task 
                <input type="button" name="btnaddtask" id="btnaddtask" style="width:70px; height:30px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:normal; float:right; margin-right:30px; cursor:pointer; " value="Add Task" onclick="return go_add_tasks();" />
                <!--<input type="button" name="btnaddtask" id="btnaddtask" style="width:70px; height:30px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:normal; float:right; margin-right:30px; cursor:pointer; " value="Add Task" onclick="return pop_add_task_frm_other();" />-->            </th>
                <th width="35%">Review Task</th>
                <th width="31%">Finished Task</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <table border="1" style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <?php 
                                /*...................................The Tasks selects here which are Added by this user..............................................*/
                                if($list_3){
                                $i=0;
                                foreach($list_3 as $row3){ 
                                $added_id = $row3['TravancoMarketing']['id'];
                                ?>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row3['TravancoMarketing']['title'];?>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="set_task_id" id="set_task_id_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $row3['TravancoMarketing']['id'];?>" />

                                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('...View More', '/TravancoMarketing/MarketingListaddedtask/'.$added_id, array('class'=>'textlinkclass', 'target'=>'_self')); ?>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                 <?php 
                                 $i++;
                                 } ?>
                                 <tr>
                        <?php echo $this->paginator->numbers(); ?>


                        </td>
                      </tr> 
                      <?php } ?>
                    </table>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <table border="1" style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <?php 
                                /*................................The Tasks selects here which are Added by this user(Pending Tasks)..................................*/
                                $i=0;
                                if($list_2){
                                foreach($list_2 as $row2){ 
                                $review_id = $row2['TravancoMarketing']['id'];
                                ?>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row2['TravancoMarketing']['title'];?>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="review_task_id" id="review_task_id_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $row2['TravancoMarketing']['id'];?>" />
                                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('...View More', '/TravancoMarketing/MarketingListpendingtask/'.$review_id, array('class'=>'textlinkclass', 'target'=>'_self')); ?>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                 <?php 
                                 $i++;
                                 } ?>
                                 <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $this->paginator->numbers(); ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr> 
                      <?php } ?>
                    </table>



                </td>
                <td>
                    <table border="1" style="width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <?php 
                                /*...............................The Tasks selects here which are Added by this user(Finished Tasks).................................*/
                                $i=0;
                                if($list_4){
                                foreach($list_4 as $row4){ 
                                $review_id = $row4['TravancoMarketing']['id'];
                                ?>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $row4['TravancoMarketing']['title'];?>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="review_task_id" id="review_task_id_<?php echo $i;?>" value="<?php echo $row4['TravancoMarketing']['id'];?>" />
                                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('...View More', '/TravancoMarketing/MarketingListfinishedtask/'.$review_id, array('class'=>'textlinkclass', 'target'=>'_self')); ?>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                 <?php 
                                 $i++;
                                 } ?>
                                 <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $this->paginator->numbers(); ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr> 
                      <?php } ?>
                    </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There have no pagination link displaying.this is the screen shot.[image]

But when i order of  the code in controller as like this:

```
`/*...................................The Tasks selects here which are Added by this user..............................................*/

$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('status = 1', 'user_id = '.$user_level), 'limit' => 3, 'order' => array('TravancoMarketing.id' => 'DESC' ) );
$data4 = $this->paginate('TravancoMarketing');
$this->set('list_4', $data4);/*$this->set('list_3', '');*/

/*...................................................END..............................................................................*/

/*...................................The Tasks selects here which are Added by this user..............................................*/

$this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('status = 0', 'user_id = '.$user_level), 'limit' => 3, 'order' => array('TravancoMarketing.id' => 'DESC' ) );
$data3 = $this->paginate('TravancoMarketing');
$this->set('list_3', $data3);/*$this->set('list_3', '');*/

/*...................................................END..............................................................................*/`

$this->render('Marketing/taskmanagement');

Then it will displays pagination in all section ,but that pagination not correct ,that means the pagination count is correct only for first section in this time..
```

This is the screenshot after chaing the order of the code:
[image]
    So what is the problem in my code....

```
The pagination is not working correctly in my view page.

It take the pagination links of last executed query and put this link for all section .This is the main problem in my code.

How can i solve this?
```

Comment: Please use my approach explained [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21211278/2486198

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I believe it's not technically possible to use the built-in pagination to paginate multiple models on a single page, due to there being no way for CakePHP to actually know what specific model to paginate as all the links from the paginator helper come in the form of `/controller/action/page:1` - and CakePHP has no way knowing what model `page1` relates to.

Personally I would recommend taking an ajax approach.

Comment: Unfortunately it's quite a task, you'd want to setup and action for each model you want to paginate, put the pagination for just that model in, then alter the pagination links to use ajax to the new actions.(you could remove the original pagination calls and replace them with finds in your `MarketingTaskmanagement` action.