# Assign Custom values to the $paginator->numbers in Cakephp Pagination

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

heres my situation, I have a user dashboard with tabs in it:

1. 1st tab shows user projects that are active
2. 2nd tab shows user projects that are expired.

along with a bunch of other tabs.

The problem started when I tried to paginate Tab1 and Tab2. I have the relative question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305839/cakephp-two-separate-paginations-of-the-same-model). This question has been answered by [petrocket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5878734/) although it does not work entirely.

The problem with the paginated links and counter remains.

when I do

```
<?php pr($this->Paginator->params['paging']); ?>
```

I get the following result:

```
Array (
    [UserProject] => Array
    (
        [page] => 1
        [current] => 1
        [count] => 8
        [prevPage] => 
        [nextPage] => 1
        [pageCount] => 8
        [order] => UserProject.id Desc
        [limit] => 1
        [options] => Array
            (
            )
        [paramType] => named
    )

    [UserProject2] => Array
    (
        [page] => 1
        [current] => 1
        [count] => 5
        [prevPage] => 
        [nextPage] => 1
        [pageCount] => 5
        [order] => UserProject2.id Desc
        [limit] => 1
        [options] => Array
            (
            )
        [paramType] => named
    )
)
```

**My question is:** Is there any way by which we can manually change the value of paginator *counter*, *next*, *previous*, *first* and *last* values?

My assumption is that if I can specify these values manually from the above array it will work fine. Right now it just takes the value of array `[UserProject]` correctly but not for array `[UserProject2]`.

Comment: does `$this->Paginator->params['paging']['UserProject2']['nextPage'] = '3';` Not work?

Comment: @LetterSticker : It sort of work (partially...)
Thing is if Tab1 has 8 pages and Tab2 have 3 pages.
When i click on page 2 on Tab1 , Tab2 also changes to page 2 and vice versa...
And if i click on page 8 in Tab1, Tab2 tries imitate it, since there are not records it will be empty on Tab2...