# Cake PHP paginate multiple tables of one model

Tags: php, database, cakephp, pagination

community,
there is a problem with multiple tables which receive their entries of the same model "Post" on the same page. When clicking a paginator-number the app will change the page for both tables.

I tried it with dummy classes in the AppModel which should work but I get an error saying an internal error has occurred (error 500). I found out that there is a problem with the corresponding SQL-statement with a not found row.

In the AppModel:

```
class PostHood extends Post {
    public $useTable = 'posts';
};
```

That code uses the table "cake_posts" of "class Post extends AppModel". In the controller I tried to get the PostHood like following:

```
$this->paginate['PostHood'] = array(
    'conditions' => array('OR' => array(stuff)),
    'limit' => 5
);
$this->set('postsHood', $this->paginate('PostHood'));
```

In the view there is a foreach-loop using the $postsHood as $post.
Maybe you have an idea, thanks in advance :)

EDIT 1:
I got some error notices after changing the code. May be you have an idea what to do.
Change of the AppModel:

```
class PostHood extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    public $useTable = 'posts';
};
```

The Controller:

```
$this->loadModel('PostHood');
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('OR' =>
    array(
        array('AND' => array(   
        array('PostHood.ZIPCODE LIKE' => $userArea . '%'),
            array('PostHood.ALTDATE >' => date("Y-m-d")),
        array('PostHood.AGENT' => '0'),
        array('PostHood.OWNER <>' => $this->UserAuth->getUserId()),
        array('PostHood.PARENTID' => '0'),
        array('PostHood.ACCEPTED' => '0')
    )), [MORE AND ARRAYS]
$this->set('postsHood', $this->paginate('PostHood'));
```

The corresponding error in the view:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Post.DATE' in 'order clause'
```

SQL Query: SELECT `PostHood`.`id`, `PostHood`.`B/S`, `PostHood`.`H`, `PostHood`.`CITY`,
 `PostHood`.`MARKET`, `PostHood`.`DATE`, `PostHood`.`ALTDATE`, `PostHood`.`TIME`, `PostHood`.`INCOME`, `PostHood`.`ZIPCODE`, `PostHood`.`ALIAS`, `PostHood`.`VEHICLE`, `PostHood`.`DELIVERYAREA`, `PostHood`.`SPACE`, `PostHood`.`STREET`, `PostHood`.`HOUSENUMBER`, `PostHood`.`NAME`, `PostHood`.`CART`, `PostHood`.`TEL`, `PostHood`.`OWNER`, `PostHood`.`created`, `PostHood`.`modified`, `PostHood`.`AGENT`, `PostHood`.`EXTRADATA`, `PostHood`.`PARENTID`, `PostHood`.`BRATED`, `PostHood`.`SRATED`, `PostHood`.`REQUESTED`, `PostHood`.`ACCEPTED` FROM `usr_web126986_4`.`cake_posts` AS `PostHood` WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `Post`.`DATE` asc LIMIT 5

Obviously Cake tries to fetch data with "PostHood" but the table "posts" which I actually want to use is listening to "Post.field". How can I fix that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the great plugin DataTables. That overrides the cake-pagination and uses JSON to display the results.

In order to implement it into cake you need

1.) a cake component for interpreting sql-statements: https://github.com/cnizzdotcom/cakephp-datatable

2.) the plugin: http://www.datatables.net/index

3.) implementation:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'Model.field2'),
    'conditions' => array( stuff )
);
$response = $this->DataTable->getResponse();
$this->set('response', $response);
$this->set('_serialize','response');
$encode = json_encode($response);
$this->set('dataTablesData', $encode);
```

Then you can grab the data in the view.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array('OR' => array(stuff)),
    'limit' => 5
);
$this->set('postsHood', $this->paginate('PostHood'));
```

I am just curious as to why you want to structure your model extending another model.

Comment: Hi Thorpe, that doesn´t work. My question is very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305839/cakephp-two-separate-paginations-of-the-same-model I tried to implement the last answer there but it doesn´t work.